# Select first few rows of pandas dataframe with a certain value in the column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to set values of a column in a pandas dataframe based on the value of another column,

```
df2.loc[df2['col1',len] == val, 'col2'] = df1['col2']
```

Above code works fine, however, now the problem is that I want to set values only for first few rows, something like below:

```
len1 = len(df1.index)
df2.loc[df2['col1',len1] == val, 'col2'] = df1['col2']
```

But I am getting following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "...\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1945, in get_loc
>     return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>   File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)
>   File "pandas\index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)
>   File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)
> ```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this:

```
df2.iloc[:len(df1.index),].ix[df2.col1 == val, 'col2'] = df1['col2']
```

Here it is working not sure what's wrong with it.

```
    name gender  age occupation  years_of_school married
0    Bob      M   37    Dentist               20       N
1  Sally      F   21    Student               16       N
2    Jim      M   55  Carpenter               12       Y
3    Dan      M   27    Teacher               18       Y
4   Rose      F   14    Student                9       N
5  Emily      F   65    Retired               22       Y



  age_range
0       mid
1     young
2       old
3     young
4     young
```

Here is a sample query on it:

```
df.iloc[:len(df1.index),].ix[df.age > 25, 'occupation'] = df1['age_range']
```

Here is what it returns:

```
    name gender  age occupation  years_of_school married
0    Bob      M   37        mid               20       N
1  Sally      F   21    Student               16       N
2    Jim      M   55        old               12       Y
3    Dan      M   27      young               18       Y
4   Rose      F   14    Student                9       N
5  Emily      F   65    Retired               22       Y
```

I am not receiving any copying a slice errors. That might be because of the way you created or massaged your DataFrames previously but I just did this with no errors and no problems. Unless I misunderstood your original question then I don't understand why the down votes, and even then no explanation of why down voting so that I can fix it.

Comment: But it does not change the values of col2 inside df2.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: Edited my answer to show it works. Also if you are going to down vote please comment as to why you did not like it so I can fix it so that you and other users may receive the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Apologies, vote down was by mistake, I was kind of testing the arrows.